# Pandas to_sql funtion error: in has_table assert schema is not None

Tags: mysql, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

Hi I am Trying to load Pandas Dataframe data into my MySQL table, Iam using to_sql() funtion but its showing Assertion error: in has_table assert schema is not None.
this is my code below:

my_conn= create_engine(url)
print(my_conn)

data=pd.read_csv("D:\Souce_files\sample_CSV\email.csv",sep=';',header=0)

data.to_sql(con=my_conn,name='Landing_layer',if_exists='append',index=False)

Ideally it should load data in mySQL table or if table doesn't exists it should create itself.
But I am not sure is it environment problem or Library's Bug.